# Automapper 5.2 with inheritance not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, automapper-5

I have an Entity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
     public Int16 Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Certificate : BaseEntity
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Authority { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecieveDate { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a ViewModel:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public Int16 Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Certificate : BaseViewModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Authority { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecieveDate { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map Entity.Certificate to ViewModel.Certificate (I don't really need to map BaseEntity at all, I want to get rid of it).
I have Mapper profile:

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
 {
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Storage.Entities.Entities.BaseEntity, ViewModels.ViewModels.BaseViewModel>()
            .Include<Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate, ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate>();
        CreateMap<Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate, ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate>();
    }
 }
```

Registered in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

All 3 classes mentioned above are in different projects (if it makes any sence).

This is controller constructor:

```
    private readonly Storage.Abstractions.Core.IStorage _storage;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public CertificateController(Storage.Abstractions.Core.IStorage storage, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this._storage = storage;
        this._mapper = mapper;
    }
```

And Get Method where I map entity to viewModel:

```
   IEnumerable<Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate> certificates = await this._storage.GetRepository<ICertificateRepository>().AllAsync();
   IEnumerable<ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate>result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate>, IEnumerable<ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate>>(certificates);
```

Looks correct, right?
BUT:

Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
IEnumerable`1 -> IEnumerable`1
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[AlexanderTsema.Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate, AlexanderTsema.Storage.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[AlexanderTsema.ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate, AlexanderTsema.ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

and Inner Exc:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Certificate -> Certificate
AlexanderTsema.Storage.Entities.Entities.Certificate -> AlexanderTsema.ViewModels.ViewModels.Certificate

Please advice.

I tried to map Entity.Certificate to Entity.Certificate and it works fine.

Comment: Read the help center articles before posting a quiestion http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging especially the **Should I use tags in titles?**  section: _Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats: [tag]: [question title]_

Comment: @user2970104 Quick questions, though. What signature of `AddAutoMapper` does IntelliSense show you if you remove all arguments from it? What platform do you use, the full .NET Framework or is it a .NET Core application? I'm trying to understand why calling it with no parameters didn't work.

Comment: bot edits question title :( It's ASP.NET Core 1.1. Intellisense doesn't show anything specific. @MickaëlDerriey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be missing is at least one type or assembly  that AutoMapper could use to discover profiles.

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));` should do the trick.